# Parsing a half XML, half text file with Scala

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing

I need to parse, out of a huge log file (~2M lines), a few hundred lines regarding informations of specific users. These lines I need are enclosed in XML delimiters, however the file presents many free text notifications; stuff like "2016-06-08 06:00:00,289 [HSBLink] DEBUG HSBLink_5 - Received MSG", which I don't care about.

I am completely new to Scala but I have a Java background. I was wondering which way should I go: to parse the whole thing as XML somehow, and then ignore most of it, or to parse it as free text and search in it for the identifiers I care about, and the text enclosed.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post some demo data for the file.

Comment: Without knowing more about the format, it's not really possible to give a good answer. But if it's not (entirely) XML, parsing it as XML probably is not going to work  But I'm really not sure what you're expecting by posting the question - there's no magic answer just because it's Scala, you'll need to write some code, and from what you've said, that should be straightforward

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Unfortunately I am not able to share my code as it belongs to my company; however, it consists in long series of these useless notifications, and then some infos delimited within XML tags, e.g., 

<notif:UsefulData date="2016-01-01" id="123456">
....(data enclosed in tags)
</notif:UsefulData>.

I was wondering whether there maybe was some tool that recognises XML portions of a file, or something like that. I am currently solving it by reading the file and parsing by calling "contains". Just wondering if there was a more clever approach for me to take.

Comment: Not really. If the notif is on a new line, I wouldn't even use scala, just preprocess it with `sed` (assuming a Unix-like OS)